# Treating < and > as synonyms for the curly braces { and }

Tags: catcodes, braces

I am exporting photo metadata from a software which seems to be unable to export curly braces correctly. Is there any way to tell LaTeX to treat `<` as `{`, and `>` as `}`, to keep me from having to go through the file manually? In the back of my head I have cat-codes in mind but never used them so far.

Comment: it might be easier to write a script which fixes the data formatting, and not have to redefine things in LaTeX, but that's not what you asked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\catcode`\<=1
\catcode`\>=2
```

does what you ask although you might find some parts of LaTeX are not expecting to find < and > redefined like that.

Constructs such as `\ifnum\tempdim<5pt` fail if `<` is not `<` but you don't normally find those mid document so switch catcodes after `begin{document}` perhaps by making your application write out just the main body of the document without the preamble and then have a document with normal syntax that looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}


\input{file-with-anglebrackets}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this leave math-related operators untouched?

Comment: @Werner well you can do `$\left\langle \frac<1><2> \right\rangle$` but not `$\left< \frac<1><2> \right>$` if that's what you mean

Comment: I just checked an example, it seems that LaTeX doesn't like me to change `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass<article>`

Comment: This is partly what I meant, but good to know. I was referring to `x > y` which I guess has to be replaced with `x \gt y`.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen, I'm adding some note to the answer, too long for comment

Comment: I helped myself by just exporting CSV and using datatool. I contacted the author of the Lightroom plugin, it would be great to have it export LaTeX directly.

Comment: Probably wise:-)